# Converting std::pair of iterators to boost::iterator_range

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, boost-range

I have a `std::multimap`, and I want to create a `boost::iterator_range` from `equal_range`. I found no simple way of doing it in the documentation, so I tried the following:

```
typedef std::multimap<int, std::string> Map;
Map map;
...
boost::iterator_range<Map::iterator> r(map.equal_range(2));
```

Surprisingly, it works (using GCC 4.1.2). I am curious how it works. I found no overload for `iterator_range` constructor that would do it, and `multimap::iterator_range` obviously has no overload that would return Boost ranges.

Comment: Note that there is also `boost::make_iterator_range` that deduces the underlying iterator type from the pair.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`iterator_range_core.hpp`:

```
//! Constructor from a Range
template< class Range >
iterator_range( const Range& r ) :
    m_Begin( impl::adl_begin( r ) ), m_End( impl::adl_end( r ) )
{}
```

`impl::adl_begin` takes you to `boost::begin`. Having a look at `begin.hpp` we see (among other *voodoo*):

```
template< typename Iterator >
inline Iterator range_begin( const std::pair<Iterator,Iterator>& p )
{
    return p.first;
}
```

And for an example how types can be “adapted” into ranges have a look [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/extending/method_2.html) (they use `pair` as an example).